# React Native android support-v4 not working

Tags: android, react-native, android-support-library

I am new to react native, while create first project by command

> react-native init AwesomeProject

after that to run the project by command

> react-native run-android

getting error for support-v4 library, screenshot attached [image]

below is setting for version -

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 26
targetSdkVersion = 26
supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
 }
```

please provide any solution for this problem.

Comment: you should open project in android studio and install the missing part

Comment: after import project with existing source in studio structure of project changes, and please share steps to install library

Answer (score 0):

instead of react native init you should use CRNA it is much better and simple

```
$ npm i -g create-react-native-app
$ create-react-native-app AwsomeProject
$ cd AwsomeProject
$ npm run android
```

Comment: I want to create project using react-native, i dont want to use expo.

Comment: I never use react-native init i always use CRNA along with genymotion. install genymotion or any other emulator and follow above steps you can enjoy it. It is pretty fast. I think its worth a try.

Comment: I have a project which is already created in react-native, so i want help on this. can not use expo

Comment: but if you still want to use react-native init then update "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.+' " and and my gradle wrapper to "distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip" in your gradle file